Charge density arising due to a moving electric dipole should be time-dependent
Recently, I was reading an article that was trying to refute Fisher's claim regarding the expression for the magnetic moment developed due to a moving electric dipole. According to Fisher, the value comes out to be $$\mathbf{m} = \mathbf{m_0} - \frac{1}{2c}(\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{p_0})$$
where $\mathbf{m_0}$ and $\mathbf{p_0}$ are the rest-frame magnetic and electric dipole moments, respectively. This expression is approximated to the first order in $\beta$. The paper tries to prove that the actual expression is
$$\mathbf{m} = \mathbf{m_0} - \frac{1}{c}(\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{p_0})$$
They state that Fisher's approximation fails as the charge density due to a moving electric dipole should not be time-independent. Why should this hold in general for every case? Does it create a problem if the divergence of the current density($\mathbf{J}$) is zero?
